# I came over this question of Inheritance in an exam and was confused with output.. can you tell me the correct answer and why

Tags: java, object, inheritance, polymorphism

```
class HE{
    public void m1(double num)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello HE"+ num);
    }
}

class H extends HE{
    public void m1(int num)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello H" + num);
    }
}
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HE obj= new H();
        obj.m1(10);
    }
}
```

So if the HE class has argument of type double it calls that class but if argument data type is changed to int it goes to H class but even though the object is calling H class only. Can you please tell me why. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

`obj` is a variable of type `HE`.

The compiler searches for methods called `m1` on the `HE` class, because that's the type of `obj`. It doesn't look at the type assigned to the variable at runtime.

The only method on `HE` is `m1(double)`, so that's the one which is invoked.